# C# Universal App Canvas Object Bigger Than Scrollview

Tags: c#, scrollview, zooming, win-universal-app, pinchzoom

```html
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrview"
                        ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      Margin="50,50,0,0"
                      Height="400" Width="1000" 
                      BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
                      BorderThickness="2"
                      ManipulationMode="All"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      MinZoomFactor="2"
                      MaxZoomFactor="5000"
                      DoubleTapped="ScrollViewer_DoubleTapped">
                <Canvas x:Name="recGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I have a canvas object which include Rectangles.Become create this canvas, it will bigger than the Scrollview. I try to zoom out to see all of Rectangels but it can not work. I can zoom in but not zoom out.

Does anyone has idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrview"
                        ZoomMode="Enabled" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      Margin="50,50,0,0"
                      Height="400" Width="1000" 
                      BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
                      BorderThickness="2"
                      ManipulationMode="All"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      MinZoomFactor="2"
                      MaxZoomFactor="5000"
                      DoubleTapped="ScrollViewer_DoubleTapped">
                <Canvas x:Name="recGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```